# БСП? Неоднородное?

Tags: бсп

1. Трепачи-связисты вызнали: все вы представлены к званию Героя Советского Союза.
2. Лодки с понтонами крепко охранялись – заречные вояки очень были озабочены важными делами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно. В первом предложении объектные отношения, во втором - временная связь.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!